# How to replace ModalRef with LaunchDialogService in Composable Storefront

Tags: spartacus-storefront

The ModalService, ModalDirective, ModalDirectiveOptions, ModalDirectiveService, ModalOptions and ModalRef have all been removed from composable storefront 5.0. If you are using the ModalService and related code in your composable storefront application, you can replace it with the LaunchDialogService, which can be imported from @spartacus/storefront.

```js
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.openModal(CalculateModalComponent, {
      centered: true,
      size: 'lg',
      scrollable: true,
      windowClass: 'finance-calculator-modal',
      ariaLabelledBy: AccessibilityConstants.MODAL_TITLE_ID,
    });
    modalInstance = this.modalRef.componentInstance;
    modalInstance.productCode = this.wishlistProduct.code;
```

Comment: It is all described in the relase notes of version 5:
https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_COMPOSABLE_STOREFRONT/10a8bc7f635b4e3db6f6bb7880e58a7d/7266f6f01edb4328b4e09df299ea09be.html?locale=en-US&version=5.0#loioecdab1705c844e2a867b49d923bf4096

Comment: Yes, it is all poorly described as usual on SAP documentation. In the entire doc, this is the only place that mention the most basic scenario. Is there any doc about the service itself? With examples? For instance, I'm practically the whole day trying to close the dialog from another component and I can't figure it out. How can I open a dialog with LaunchDialogService in a component and close it on a dialog button click on dialog's component?!